# How to ignore UAC while silent installing VLC

Tags: batch-file, installation, exe

My question is how do I get the installation of VLC media player in a batch script done without having to accept the UAC prompt during the installation.

What I have till now is this - working for a silent installation but still wanting me to press the UAC button.

```
vlc-2.1.1-win64.exe /S
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to circumvent UAC only using the technique to create a scheduled task that has administrator privileges to run and then create a shortcut to run this scheduled task, this shortcut when it runs, it runs automatically without asking permission, without the button Yes or No to appear, look at the tutorial link below to better understand.

[Run UAC restricted programs without the UAC prompt](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/run-uac-restricted-programs-without-the-uac-prompt/)

Comment: your link was very helpful for my kind of problem but it didn't solve the main thing behind my idea. My idea was to have one batch file which I execute on a new PC. For your solution it's necessary to have the tasks in the task sceduler saved to do what I want.

Comment: You can follow the tutorial so that you indicate the file as executable task is a batch script that receives parameters, based on the parameters you do the programming you want, for example script.bat "VLC" or script.bat "WINRAR" (VLC and WINRAR as parameters/arguments". Getting the parameter %~1 equal to VLC, you configure the goto command to go to the label :VLC and proceeding with the silent installation of VLC Player, if %~1 parameter equals "WINRAR" use the goto command to the label :winrar and so on. The only job you have is to create this single task on the PC.